# Complex logarithm of $(1-z)$ on $\{z:\Re(z) < 1\}$

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-analysis

I'm not sure how to approach this question. Can someone please give me a hint?

If $h(z)$ is analytic on $\Omega:=\{z:\Re(z) < 1\}$ and $\exp(h(z))=1-z$, $\forall z \in \Omega$ and $h(0) = 0$. Prove that $|\Im(h(z))| < \pi/2$, $\forall z \in \Omega$.

Thank you.

Comment: $h(z)=\log(1-z)$. The condition $h(0)=0$ and $z\in \Omega$ determines the branch. That's exactly the condition that the imaginary part of $h(z)$ is larger than $-\pi/2$ and smaller than $\pi/2$.

Comment: That doesn't mean anything to me, sorry. I have never heard of the term "branch". In fact the text I'm using now avoids completely defining and using the complex log and only refers to it indirectly like this.

Comment: Well, maybe I can explain it in another way. $1-z>0$, so we can write it as the form $1-z=re^{i\theta}$ where $-\pi/2<\theta< \pi/2$. we can think of $h(z)$ as $\log(r) + i\theta$ (in this case the logarithm is just a real logarithm).

Comment: The function $h(z)$ defined in that way is exactly the function $h$ in your question. It is well-define, and also analytic because of the inverse function theorem.

Comment: And how exactly does the inverse function theorem come into this? What if instead of $-\pi/2 < \theta < \pi/2$ I choose $0 \leq \theta < \pi/2$, $3\pi/2 < \theta < 2\pi$ say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly the function $h$ defined in my comment is the inverse of $f \circ \exp$ where $f(z)=1-z$. It is easy to see that it is continuous as well. Moreover, $(f \circ \exp)'(z)=-\exp(z)$, and this is nonzero for all $z$ whose imaginary part is in between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$. Thus by the inverse function theorem $h$ is analytic.

You cannot choose other ranges of $\theta$ as you asked, because that does not define analytic $h$. (Be careful when choosing the range.) For instance, if you choose $0\leq \theta<\pi/2$, $2\pi/2 <\theta <2\pi$, then that function is not continuous at $1-z=1$ (that is, $\theta$ jumps from $0$ to $2\pi$).

Comment: But being continuous is not the same as being well-defined?

Comment: @ProjectBook Well, yes. I mean $h$ must be defined to be analytic and thus must be continuous... I edited that point.